# too much glue in angular2 DI or there is another way?

Tags: angular, angular2-di

in angular 1.x services were injected by specifying its registered name. For example using TypeScript:

```
// appointments.ts
export interface IAppointmentServices {
    retrieve(start: Date, end: Date): Appointment[]
}

// appointment-services.ts:
class AppointmentServices implements IAppointmentServices {
     retrieve(start: Date, end: Date): Appointment[] {
          ...
     }
}

angular.module('appointments')
       .service('AppointmentServices', AppointmentServices);

// appointment-controller.ts
class AppointmentController {
     constructor (private service: IAppointmentService) {
     }
     // pay attention that 'AppointmentServices' is the registered name
     // not a hard reference to the class AppointmentServices
     static $inject = ['AppointmentServices'] 
}
```

**pay attention that the controller implementation has no reference in any way to the file nor the class that implements the service**

but in angular 2, to accomplish a similar DI you have to something as in these lines:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {AppointmentServices} from 'appointment-services';

@Component({
    ...
    providers: [AppointmentServices]
})
export class Appointment {
    constructor (service: AppointmentServices) {
        ...
    }
}
```

pay attention that in the second import above, I have to specify the location where the AppointmentServices is implemented as well as the name of the class which represent a **glue between the component and the implementation of the service**

Is there a way in angular2 to inject the service without specifying the class and the file that implements it?

I think this angular2 approach is kind of a step back in terms of IoC accomplished in its predecessor if DI has to be done in such a way!

Answer (score 2):

There is no such way, because this is simply how `import / export` functionality works. In order to `import` something, it must be equally `exported` (by the same name), somewhere else.

Hence why in one file (appointment-services) you have

```
export class AppointmentServices
```

And the other component file you use Object Destruction to "grab" that specific thing (which was exported from it)

```
import { AppointmentServices } from 'appointment-services';
```

These two are linked, in that, that is how they access each other.  Although this may seem "backwards", TypeScript and IDEs now have the power to refactor an entire library with ease now, since they are aware of these export/imports.

So if you wanted to change it to `export class AnotherAppoinmentService` instead, you could refactor it, and your IDE could automatically switch them all for you!

> Note: Angular1 modules stored everything as "String", why things were loosely specified. You typically had to do MyClass.name for example

Comment: Nice answer :) This also allows to distinguish two services with the same name (from different libraries) to avoid unexpected collisions. It also allows proper tree-shaking because it can be tracked where identifiers came from. Libraries that are not imported are known to be unused and can be skipped. The Angular1 way is the typical JS way where you need to hope you didn't forget to name something consistently. In TypeScript, tools can provide lots of guidance but they need explicit information.

Comment: I still think this is too much glue and a step backward in terms of IoC. Take a look at http://inversify.io/ which is what I was really looking for. That's a true IoC approach because the hard dependency between a component and a service in angular2 is just not convenient